# Schema check or "DATE as separate table"

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

I'm dusting of my SQL, and would love to know if I've got my mental ER-diagram right.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5c59

Basically, I've got 10-15 different datasets (actividades) from several locations (islas) over the span of a few months. My first instinct is to separate the many-to-many relationship between Islas and Actividades into an intermediary table, then reference(/index?) each dataset by location.

If this is the correct approach, I'm then wondering whether there is any benefit to have a separate date table (I guess this would be kind of like a calender). ie: the join between location, date and dataset would give one result, querying a date and location would give a list of all the activities that day and querying a single date would give all datasets from all locations.

Or should I just datestamp each datapoint (of each dataset) and deal with this in my queries.

I hope that was legible, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great if your sqlfiddle data would have been in English...

If the activities aer bound to a single location, you could use your current approach. 
But if there's a chance that one activity can be referenced to more than one location you should use a separate table to show such a reference (using foreign keys to the primary keys of your activity and location tables).

A calendar table usually is very helpful if you'll need to return any results for a consecutive date range including date values without any corresponding values (e.g. activities).

Comment: Sorry, English is a second language.

Comment: There are seven locations, that share most of the activities, but not all of them. The approach you described is what I was trying to achieve with the intermediary table 'ActList', combining island ID and activity ID, perhaps I'm not referencing it quite right.